# SNMP MIB Structure Conventions for nodes below the Enterprise Identifier

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have developed a Linux/Umbutu program running on what will be an imbedded P-based device.  I wish for that piece of code to be able to send and receive the SNMP data for the entire product.  So, I know the OID down to the company level, 1.3.6.1.4.1.34843, and I further know that the two SNMP enabled products we sell are 1.3.6.1.4.1.34843.1 and 1.3.6.1.4.1.34843.2.  Pretty sure mine will be .3.

The question is, is there a known structure/convention for the nodes below this point?  What I read seems to imply that I can use whatever structure I want. Would ...34843.1.0 exist?  Is it a node to fetch (get) the list or max-count of same-level nodes?  Would ...34843.1.0.0 exist?  Would it make any sense?  The guy who developed the first two MIBs is out of town for a while and I can't really ask him, and I'd like to make sure I understand his answer when he gives it to me.

Is there a document that describes the required/suggested organization?  Probably some RFC, right.  So, is there a document in a language spoken by humans?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular resource is the `understanding SNMP MIBs` book by Perkins and McGinnis.  It describes MIBs in a more readable format.  The Net-SNMP [tutorials](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials) online might be helpful too, as they discuss a lot about MIBs.  If you want the RFC, then [RFC2578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578) is the right thing to read.

The quick hierarchy guidance would be something along the lines of:

1. Use 3 sections: one for objects, one for notifications, and one for conformance information
2. For notifications, root them at the .0 (see [RFC3584](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3584) for details on why)
3. For each table, you might want a scalar showing the number of objects in a table and potentially a LastChanged object for showing how frequently configuration within the table might have changed).

There is a lot more guidance that can be found in the books and other sources listed above than can be repeated here, of course.  RFCs [4181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4181), and [5249](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5249) may be helpful as well.